# Docker gitlab-runner executing one job fine but the rest fails

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using the gitlab-runner official docker image to run some jobs in a pipeline.
When I run the pipeline, I have a matrix job. The firs one of these to run will run fine, but on the other I get the error:

```
ERROR: Failed to remove network for build
ERROR: Preparation failed: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? (docker.go:887:0s)
```

This is the relevant part of `config.toml`:

```ini
concurrent = 3
[[runners]]
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "ruby:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
    network_mtu = 0
```

For context, I use podman in the host machine. I start the container with:

```
sudo docker run -d --restart always --name gitlab-runner \
        -v /run/<my path>/podman/podman.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    -v ./config.toml:/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml \
    gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
```

I already tried to add `host = "unix:///run/<my path>/podman/podman.sock"` to the `runners.docker`, but it did not help.